# PowerBulder DropDownListBox inside a Datawindow

Tags: powerbuilder

I have made a DropDownListBox inside a Datawindow.

Upon Item Change, I set and save the Value of the selected item in that DropDown in an INI File.

In my Open Event, I use setitem to Set the saved value in that dropdown.
The problem here is that it doesnt setfocus on that index of the selected item in those dropdown.

I also used, SetRow(), setcolumn(), SetText() just to make the Focusing of the Selected Text.
The problem on this one is I have like 100+ Items. When the chosen value is in the middle, let's say Index#50, the ScrollBar focus is still on the top Index#1, not at Index#50.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Powerbuilder.  Wow!  Is anybody still programming PowerBuilder this century?

Comment: Of course, it is still great :)

Comment: I tried using VB.Net for this but I can program faster using Power Builder :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Try to play with SetRedraw

```
dw.SetRedraw(false)
dw.SetItem(...)
dw.SetRedraw(true)
```

2) Try to use DDDW instead of DDLW. And use DDDW with integer index column. Sometimes builder fails with string "keys"

Comment: I was using dddw at first but I resulted into ddlb. I did not use dddw because I am just populating ddlb with For Loops of values retrieved from Registry.

Comment: And how did you polulate ddlb? and when?

Comment: Thanks, I pushed through using GetChild and populated thru that. I forgot GetChild when I was pushing dddw. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A) This is so much easier with a DDDW editstyle right in the datawindow.  You just do a SetItem( row, column, value) to set the initial value in the dropdown.

B) That having been said, I would not call 100+ items in a listbox "effective UI design".  I would evolve that into an editbox, with search-on-type capabilities, like you see in the Google search page.

Comment: I am emulating Font Style options.